# Output of additional files (detectors, induction loops) are not being generated

Tags: veins, sumo

Output of additional files (detectors, induction loops) are not being generated. I used a simple scenario, just to see how things work. But I cannot see or maybe these files are not being generated. I added them at **`launch.xml`** and **`sumo.cfg`** as additional files. This is the code for **`detector.xml`** :

```
<additional>
    <laneAreaDetector id="E2" lane="1to2_0" pos="15" endPos="20" length="20.0" friendlyPos="false" freq="5.890e9" file="ostie.xml" timeThreshold="1" speedThreshold="3.6" jamThreshold="10.0" />
</additional>
<additional>
    <inductionLoop id="myLoop1" lane="1to2_0" pos="16.0" freq="900" file="out.xml" />
    <inductionLoop id="myLoop2" lane="1to2_0" pos="100.0" freq="900" file="out.xml" />
</additional>
```

The file out is empty. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does not appear to be attached to this post - please supply it.

Comment: This is the code for detector :<additional>
   <laneAreaDetector id="E2" lane="1to2_0" 
   pos="15" endPos="20" length="20.0"  
   friendlyPos="false" freq="5.890e9"  file="ostie.xml"
   timeThreshold="1" speedThreshold="3.6" jamThreshold="10.0" 
   />  
</additional>

Comment: inductionloop:
<additional>
  <inductionLoop id="myLoop1" lane="1to2_0" pos="16.0" freq="900" file="out.xml"/>
  <inductionLoop id="myLoop2" lane="1to2_0" pos="100.0" freq="900" file="out.xml"/>

</additional>

Comment: I can see them at SUMO gui where are placed,  but the files  after simulation are empty. I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using sumo-launchd.py of Veins to run your simulation. If so, the SUMO simulation will execute in a temporary directory (that is, by default, deleted after the simulation concludes). You will either turn this off (see the output of --help) or create the output files in another directory to retain them.

Comment: You're right. It gets deleted automatically. I ran the command for the output file in the Sumo bash externally and now it generates it.

Comment: One more question, I'm doing a scenario where there is 1 route at the beginning and then it splits into 3, then merges into 1 again. I'm stopping the car in the first lane, the second car stops also, the third one reroutes in the middle lane, the fourth goes to the queue, the fifth reroutes, the sixth goes to the queue, the seventh reroutes.....why is it behaving like that? I can't understand where to change this "balancing"  or "threshold". Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a different question. Let's keep things organized - could you move this to a new question?