# Log files containing vehicle information in Veins 5.2.i1

Tags: veins, sumo

I am very new to the Veins OMNet++ environment.  I ran the example simulation and then looked for the log files.  I found the "\instant-veins-5.2-i1\Logs\VBox.log" file but I did not see the vehicle details like "Timestamp, Vehicle Node ID, Position, speed, etc.".
It had the VM info like this:

```
00:00:02.927357 Log opened 2023-04-27T03:31:51.661539800Z
00:00:02.927358 Build Type: release
00:00:02.927360 OS Product: Windows 11
00:00:02.927361 OS Release: 10.0.22621
00:00:02.927361 OS Service Pack: 
00:00:03.018921 DMI Product Name: HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15m-ed1xxx
00:00:03.022306 DMI Product Version: Type1ProductConfigId
00:00:03.022323 Firmware type: UEFI
00:00:03.022761 Secure Boot: VERR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD
00:00:03.022803 Host RAM: 12049MB (11.7GB) total, 2922MB (2.8GB)
```

I found instructions in the manual:  https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:log-output
https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/index.html
https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/RawDump.html

Each explains to use the  and   tags in the config files.  Which specific files do this go in?  What directory contains the actual log files?

Any help will be appreciated.

Update:
I see [Output of additional files (detectors, induction loops) are not being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125077/output-of-additional-files-detectors-induction-loops-are-not-being-generated) had a similar problem.

I read the following solution:
"You will either turn this off (see the output of --help)"

I am now looking for "--help".

[Veins directory on Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFm7w.png)

***Update***
I finally found the tmp directory and output files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files created by the virtual machine are accessible (by default) only from within the virtual machine, so you will need to open a terminal or a file manager the same way you opened the OMNeT++ IDE to get to the files.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!  I'm too new to cast a vote but I tried to.  Can you tell me the directory?  I have searched everywhere using the file manager.  I will paste a screenshot.